# Add / Remove header and footer dynamically

Tags: android, listview

I need to be able to add and remove headers and footers from my `ListView` dynamically.

So I initialize my activity with my headers and footers, then at some point I want to hide them, and later I need to add the previous headers and footers, and keep the same `Adapter`.

So I found this solution, but it's ugly and I really hope that there is an other way.
Basically, I have to set a null adapter to be able to add the header view, and then set an empty adapter to add the footer view. To finish I set my real adapter.

Edit: I must add that using the visibility attribute (GONE & VISIBLE) is not a solution here, because the headers & footers views must not be in the adapter during my intermediate procedure.

```
    public class TestAdapterHeader extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {
        private static String[] items = { "test 1", "test 2", "test 3", "test 4",
                "test 5", "test 6", "test 7", "test 8", "test 9", "test 10",
                "test 11", "test 12", "test 13", "test 14", "test 15", "test 16",
                "test 17", "test 18", "test 19", "test 20" };

        private ArrayAdapter mAdapter;
        private LinearLayout mParentView;
        private TextView mHeaderView, mFooterView;

        private boolean mViewsHidden = false;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            initViews();

            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        }


        private void initViews() {
            // The main layout
            mParentView = new LinearLayout(this);
            mParentView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            mParentView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

            // The button to hide the views
            Button hideViewsButton = new Button(this);
            hideViewsButton.setText("Add/Remove views");
            hideViewsButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            // The listview
            ListView listView = new ListView(this);
            listView.setId(android.R.id.list);
            listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            mParentView.addView(hideViewsButton);
            mParentView.addView(listView);

            // Set the content view
            setContentView(mParentView);

            AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 150);

            mHeaderView = new TextView(this);
            mHeaderView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            mHeaderView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            mHeaderView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            mHeaderView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            mHeaderView.setText("Header");

            mFooterView = new TextView(this);
            mFooterView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            mFooterView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            mFooterView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            mFooterView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            mFooterView.setText("Footer");


            getListView().addHeaderView(mHeaderView);
            getListView().addFooterView(mFooterView);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mViewsHidden = !mViewsHidden;

            // Remove header & footer views
            if (mViewsHidden) {
                getListView().removeHeaderView(mHeaderView);
                getListView().removeFooterView(mFooterView);
            } 
            else {
                // Remove the ListAdapter to be able to add our headerView
                setListAdapter(null);
                getListView().addHeaderView(mHeaderView);

                // Set an empty ListAdapter to be able to add our footerView
                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(TestAdapterHeader.this, -1));
                getListView().addFooterView(mFooterView);

                // Re set our Adapter
                setListAdapter(mAdapter);
            }

            mParentView.requestLayout();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you work out anything on this? I've got a similar need.

Comment: No I didn't find anything smarter than the solution I gave. But at least it works.

Answer (score 8):

Do not try to add/remove the header/footer view.

To be able to add/remove header and footer view dynamically, simply add before setting the adapter a RelativeLayout to header and footer.
After this you can add/remove what ever you want to the RelativeLayouts.

Set the size of the RelativeLayouts to WRAP_CONTENT.

Harry

Comment: Isn't setting adapter scrolling ListView to the top? That's bizzare effect. How to avoid that? Btw. everyone should thanks Google for such wonderful API... :(

Answer (score 6):

You can use below code to do the same

```
// to show the footer view
footerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 

// to hide the footer view    
footerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I'd really prefer to simply remove them. The user can reorder the items in the list, with a drag and drop system as we can see in the music app. In this situation, the headers and footers must not be in the adapter.

Comment: @Chayy your hack works for most devices and OSs and you might be stuck with it. However, i found out the hard way setListAdapter(null); & getListView().addHeaderView(mHeaderView); does not work on 2.3.5 in a reliable manner (Specifically droid 3 phone). Therefore setting the visibility might be your best option even if you don't like it.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem and heres what i did.  Add a tag to the view and find and remove it by the tag.

```
        final Button btnAddMore = new Button(this);
        btnAddMore.setTag("footer");   

        if(myList.getFooterViewsCount() >0)
        {
            View v = myList.findViewWithTag("footer");
            if(v != null)
            {
                 myList.removeFooterView(v);
            }           
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `view.setVisibility(int visibility)` View.GONE,View.VISIBLE or View.INVISIBLE

```
        ....
        if (mViewsHidden) {
            mHeaderView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mFooterView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } 
        .... 
        else {
            mHeaderView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mFooterView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } 
        ....
```

Comment: Like I explained to Maneesh, using the visibility attribute is not a solution here.

Answer (score 1):

you need add footers and headers views in listview before the setAdapter and after this you can manipulate with setVisibility

good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple!

1) Provide and **id** to the layout container of you footer.

Ex. `footer.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/parent_footer_search_list"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical">
       <TextView

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"

            android:text="Create new list"


            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:textSize="16.8sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
      </LinearLayout>
```

In the above xml, **parent_footer_search_list** is your main container id.
Now let's come back to your fragment/activity where you've inflated this footer.
So, in order to remove it,

```
LinearLayout parentContainerForFooter = (LinearLayout) footer.findViewById(R.id.parent_footer_search_list);

**yourview**.removeFooterView(parentContainerForFooter);
```

Done! This way, you are using correct android standards. **Don't** using wrap_content, visibility GONE, etc. They are just hacks !

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be one of the few solutions out there. I just tried something very similar and it worked, but I'm in the same boat. To me, it feels like a hack.

There's a few other options, like manually adding/removing/hiding the header/footer into a view outside the listview. However, you may not get the nice scrolling effect that's pretty much the point of a listview header.

I just tried setting a view to View.GONE and instead of the view vanishing, there's a gap at the top of the ListView.

Comment: You should not set View.GONE for the header view itself. You should put a linearlayout with wrap_content for height around the desired content view. You set this parent layout as header. When you want to hide or show the header you set visibility of the content view (not the parent view) to View.GONE. This way no gap will be shown. It is indeed a hack-like solution, but it works :-D

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around to this situation, though most may not like it. Just add a linear layout above and below the list view. Now you can dynamically add and remove views with the option of using visibility options. If you set the parameters to WRAP_CONTENT, then the layout will take up no space if there are no children.

Comment: Well, a view above the listview is not a header, it won't scroll with the listview. Same thing for footers.

Comment: Listview's built in header does not scroll with the list view either as far as I remember. Why can you not insert the header without any information in it and change its contents / visibility at runtime? You say you can't have them in there but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Well, my ListView can be set in an edition mode, where I can reorder and delete the items. To do that opération, I need to remove the headers and footers first, then let the user edits the listview, and when he leaves the edition mode, I re add the headers/footers. Maybe a cleaner way would be to adapt this edition mode to ignore headers and footers...

Comment: Yeah, I think it'd be easier to just ignore index 0 and index size - 1.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem- I had to dynamically add or remove header and I did it in this way:
 - I removed items from adapter and set `adapter=null;`
 - For removing: r`emoveHeaderView(mHeaderView);`
 - For adding header: `addHeaderView(mHeaderView);`
 - create adapter again and set content

It works, but without animation it looks ugly

Answer (score 0):

```
its work fine for me!  

 private void addHeaderList(){
       mListView.setAdapter(null);
       mListView.addHeaderView(headerList);

   }
   private  void removeHeaderList(){
       mListView.removeHeaderView(headerList);
   }

     just called call function before setadapter again.
            addHeaderList();
            mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using list.addFooterView(footerview) for footer and list.addHeaderView(headerview) for header.