# Android change ListView header after setting adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

As for android SDK before 19 (KitKat), it is not possible to add / change headers / footers for a listview after setting an adapter, sooo... is there anyway to change listview header on runtime?

Suppose i remove all headers and add new header and then set a new adapter? is this considered as a good design? what is the correct way to do that?

Comment: OR. You could add the header (in the form of a TextView, for instance) in a RelativeLayout and then add the ListView under it. At runtime you can change its contents as required.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502841/add-remove-header-and-footer-dynamically/26408432#26408432